# Reading temperature from files in /sys/class/thermal/ with fscanf keeps returning the same value forever

Tags: c++, c, linux, file-io

Whilst I am having better results using `fgets`, I am really puzzled by why the following code would always give the same value (from the second read onwards).

The following is a minimal temperature reader. It seems to read correctly the first time but outputs the same value forever, despite the system temperature changes.

To do a comparison, current, effective temperature can be monitored with the command `watch cat /sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp`

Here's the code (compile with `g++ filename.cpp` ):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <signal.h>

bool shouldStop = false;

void sigHandler(int signo) {
    if(signo == SIGTERM) {
        shouldStop = true;
    }   
    else if(signo == SIGINT) {
        printf("Bye bye");
        shouldStop = true;
    }   
}   

void temperatureReadLoop() {
    FILE *fp;
    fp = fopen("/sys/class/thermal/thermal_zone0/temp", "r");
    int temperature;
    while(!shouldStop) {
        fscanf(fp, "%d", &temperature);
        printf("\ntemperature read : %d", temperature);
        // //rewind(fp);
        fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
        sleep(1);
    }   
    fclose(fp);
    printf("\nquit\n");
}   

int  main() {

    signal(SIGTERM, sigHandler);
    signal(SIGINT, sigHandler); // STOP WITH [CTRL + C]
    temperatureReadLoop();
 
}
```

Running the above results in an infinite

```
    temperature read : 44000
    temperature read : 44000
    temperature read : 44000
    temperature read : 44000
    temperature read : 44000
```

...despite the temperature is changing.
I tried resetting the file seek position in different ways but I had no luck.
It's almost like fscanf has its own hidden buffer that it's not reset.

It's worth noting that if the temperature changes between the first and the second read, the change gets through and the temperature value is correctly updated but this happens only if, by luck, the temperature changes between first and second read; it remains the same for the rest of the run time.

What am I missing?

Comment: Do basic error checking. Check return values of `fscanf` and `fseek`. Call `perror` when they fail. My guess is that `fseek` is not supported on that sysfs file. Anyway, it's always the right thing to do to do error checking and at a minimum it will aid debugging.

Comment: Not sure how those system files work with concurrent reading and writing. Did you try to use `fopen` and `flose` in the loop?

Comment: @kaylum Thanks, I'll try that as soon as I can and update

Comment: @Gerhardh No I haven't tried. Will certainly do later. Thanks!

Comment: @user3121023 But that's what I intend to do. The temp file is a one-liner with the current temperature value so I always want to read the 1st line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should call [fflush()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fflush) before your fseek().

Fseek will correctly handle updates from within your program but it does not know about external changes.

Comment: Daaaaaaaaamn! You sniper! Just tested, that works. Where is this documented? All examples I found in fseek docs don't mention this (or I read in the wrong places).

Comment: Isn't flushing an input stream undefined behaviour?

Comment: @Gerhardh From the man pages:
       For input streams associated with seekable files (e.g., disk files, but not pipes or terminals), fflush() discards any buffered data that has been fetched from
       the underlying file, but has not been consumed by the application.

Comment: From C11: 7.21.5.2: fflush... Description: "If stream points to an output stream or an update stream in which the most recent operation was not input, the fflush function causes any unwritten data for that stream to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; otherwise, the behavior is undefined." I am not sure what exactly is an "update stream". But also if such a file is considered an "update stream" doing `fflush`  after a read ( != most recent operation not input) would be undefined.

Comment: Or explicitely mentioned in "J.2 Undefined behaviour": "- The stream for the fflush function points to an input stream or to an update stream in which the most recent operation was input (7.21.5.2)." We could not be sure if there was any output since last input.